# Installing mysql-workbench from the testing ppa (Jessie) in Wheezy

Tags: apt, debian

I would like to install some packages from the testing branch without switching to it if possible. The big packages are things like `xfce4` and `mysql-workbench`. I've done this by making a testing.list file containing the deb sources for jessie/testing.
Sadly, whenever I try to install a big package from the testing branch the following happends:

```
  sem@debian:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench/testing
```

Results in

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '6.1.7+dfsg-1' (Debian:testing [amd64]) for 'mysql-workbench'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.7.2-5 is to be installed
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)
                   Depends: mysql-workbench-data (= 6.1.7+dfsg-1) but 5.2.40+dfsg-2 is to be installed
                   Depends: python-pyodbc (>= 2.1.8) but 2.1.7-1+b1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried generic solutions like `sudo apt-get -f install` but no luck. Can anyone help?

Comment: Using `aptitude` will give you a lot more options. Also, if you haven't read about apt pinning, that will provide good information on mixing branches without complete upgrading.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  aptitude update

  aptitude install mysql-workbench
```